# Display all combinations of numbers based on a sum chosen

Tags: python, numbers, combinations

Recently, I've inserted a code:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
s = sum(partial)

# check if the partial sum is equals to target
if s == target: 
    print(partial, target)
if s >= target:
    return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    n = numbers[i]
    remaining = numbers[i+1:]
    subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n]) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
subset_sum([1, 2, 3] + [1, 2, 3], 5)
```

The goal is to obtain all combinations of numbers listed that can be added together in order to meet a required sum. For example, I have two lists [1,2,3] and [2,3,4], and the goal is to get all the combinations of these numbers that are equal to 3. The answer should be [1,2] and so on..

But the problem is that I need Python to select only one element from each list, not more. How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Create Sets from the lists and itarate on one of the sets,and look for the diffrance of sum and the number from set1 in set2.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```py
target = 5

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

combinations = {(x,y) for x in a for y in b if x+y==target}
```

It iterates on the first list and the second list and adds pairs only if they add up to your desired target.

However, since `a` and `b` are not sets, there can be duplicate entries and therefore duplicate tuples. So I suggest you convert them to sets before proceeding, something along these lines:

```py
set_a = {x for x in a}
```

This also is the reason why I put the results into a set. It'll get very messy very quickly for duplicate entries and large sizes.